# How fill the missing values in the dataframe as ffill() function needs nan/None which are not in my dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As in the question above, is there any other way to do it? Because I care about not using values np.nan.

Input dataframe:

```
col_1
a
x
b
x
x
c
x
```

Output:

```
col_1
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
```

Comment: Could you give more details and some code ? data are letters ? or int ? or what kind of data is it ? if ffill is not good for you, what is your expected output ? you can use Scikit has different kind of missing data handling methods available here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, a quick way could be:

```
df["col_1"].str.replace("^x$", lambda x: np.nan).ffill()
```

So, instead of rebuilding a `ffill` logic, just try to leverage the existing one.